# Table Structure in Beautiful Soup (new)

Tags: python

When i inspect a webpage, the information i want to pull out is contained within:

```
<table class="Buy-Table" id="Book">
<tbody>
    <tr class="position" data-pos="1">
        <td class="time">16:50</td>
        <td class="Price">0.26</td>
```

I want to pull out price. But Price is a class used multiple times and so is position.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I thought this would be done using `find_parent` on Price. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `table#Book td.Price` (select `<td>` with class `Price` that is under `<table>` with `id="Book"`):

```
data = '''<table class="Buy-Table" id="Book">
<tbody>
    <tr class="position" data-pos="1">
        <td class="time">16:50</td>
        <td class="Price">0.26</td>'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

price = soup.select_one('table#Book td.Price').text

print(price)
```

Prints:

```
0.26
```

Method `select_one()` select just one item. If you want to select multiple items, use `select()` method.

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Comment: Thanks, sorry i am new so still learning. I try the above and get: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @PureJ Did you run the code as it is in my example? Or you supplied your own data? My version of `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1` and Python 3.6.8